# Using Regular expression in VS 2012

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2012

I m trying to find,using a `Regular expression` in VS 2012, all the string that matchs a string with that format :

```
<data anything here>
</data>
```

Comment: Do you mean you're using the find tool with a regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regex**

```
\<data ([^\>]+)\>\r\n\<\/data\>
```

**Regex Description:**

```
\< matches the character < literally
data  matches the characters data  literally (case insensitive)
1st Capturing group ([^\>]+)
    [^\>]+ match a single character not present in the list below
    Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    \> matches the character > literally
\> matches the character > literally
\r matches a carriage return (ASCII 13)
\n matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
\< matches the character < literally
\/ matches the character / literally
data matches the characters data literally (case insensitive)
\> matches the character > literally
```

***Notes:*** This will capture the `anything here` text into capture group 1 which you can access in visual studio replace with the `$1` symbol.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
^<data ([^>]+)>\r\n</data>
```